# multiple cells in one row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have read a few posts about what I need but I can't manage to do this.
I want a table that could be set up like an image, it will have a regular background image and from half the screen to the bottom i want the table view to have 6 different cells

[image]

How can I do this. I have done this with **buttons** and my app is working with no problems, but I wanna do this with **table** also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spire you can easily add six buttons in one table row or three buttons in one row (two rows then). You can easily assign tag number (based on indexPath.row.. like indexPath.row + 1, indexPath.row + 2 ...etc).  and in there action method you can use these tag numbers...

to create customized cells follow these links -

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). Its an extension of uitableview and you need not worry much about other things.

Comment: well i waned to learn "how to". thx for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 1):

The image doesn't look like a table view. It should be a custom view. `UITableView` can contain single `UITableViewCell` per row. If you still want to create a table view like that, you have to customize each cell to have three different views like that.

If you don't want table view, you should customize your view to achieve something like that.